# Filling missing values by id in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
company_id     established_date   othervariables   location
IX133           2003                               Paris
IX133           
IX133
IX133
IX133           2006                               Istanbul
IX133
IX133           
TY213           1995                               New York
TY213
TY213
IGG12           2004                               Milan
IGG12
IGG12
IGG12 
IZZX1
IZZX1
I24TT           1998                               Oslo
I24TT           
I24TT
```

For each `company_id - location`, I wanted established_date and location to be present on each column. How to do that?

Expected output is the following, please notice IX133 has an establishment at both Paris and Istanbul:

```
   company_id     established_date   othervariables   location
    IX133           2003                               Paris
    IX133           2003                               Paris
    IX133           2003                               Paris 
    IX133           2003                               Paris
    IX133           2006                               Istanbul
    IX133           2006                               Istanbul
    IX133           2006                               Istanbul
    TY213           1995                               New York
    TY213           1995                               New York
    TY213           1995                               New York
    IGG12           2004                               Milan
    IGG12           2004                               Milan
    IGG12           2004                               Milan
    IGG12           2004                               Milan
    IZZX1          
    IZZX1
    I24TT           1998                               Oslo
    I24TT           1998                               Oslo 
    I24TT           1998                               Oslo
```

Comment: `df.groupby('company_id').ffill()` ?

Comment: Same company might be present at different locations and established_Data changes

Comment: Let me edit the question... dataframe is not properly formatted

Comment: I edited it ,the problem is with observations like IX133

Comment: Its the same output as `df.groupby('company_id').ffill()` no? can you explain

Comment: I don't get the desired output because it is not well sorted as in the example, so the observation is  IX133 - Istanbul but it comes before the row that location and established_date information is present... Probably I have to solve it manually

Comment: I think if you use `df['location'].ffill(inplace=True)` And then `df.groupby(['company_id', 'location']).ffill()` you get the correct results @anky_91

Comment: Then your question is not well formatted. Plus this is definitely something you can solve with `pandas` without doing it manually. It's just that you have to ask your question correct instead of letting us guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean by replacing the empty strings with `NaN`s and then `groupby` and `ffill` and replace the `NaN`s back to empty strings:

```
>>> df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('company_id', as_index=False).ffill().fillna('')
   company_id established_date othervariables  location
0       IX133             2003                    Paris
1       IX133             2003                    Paris
2       IX133             2003                    Paris
3       IX133             2003                    Paris
4       IX133             2006                 Istanbul
5       IX133             2006                 Istanbul
6       IX133             2006                 Istanbul
7       TY213             1995                 New York
8       TY213             1995                 New York
9       TY213             1995                 New York
10      IGG12             2004                    Milan
11      IGG12             2004                    Milan
12      IGG12             2004                    Milan
13      IGG12             2004                    Milan
14      IZZX1                                          
15      IZZX1                                          
16      I24TT             1998                     Oslo
17      I24TT             1998                     Oslo
18      I24TT             1998                     Oslo
>>>
```